# Make all attribute names lowercase using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, lowercase, jdom

I would like to parse an XML document and change the attribute names to lowercase using JDOM.

For example, I would like the following:

```
<record ID="1" name="Dom" />
<record iD="2" nAmE="Bob" />
```

To become:

```
<record id="1" name="Dom" />
<record id="2" name="Bob" />
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using JDOM 2.0.2 you could probably use an XPath, and loop the names. The problem is that you could end up with a conflict if, for example, an Element has multiple attributes that resolve to the same lower-case names, like 'ID' and 'id'.... but that is something you probably won't have to deal with.

Try some code like (will only return attributes in the no-namespace namespace):

```
XPathExpression<Attribute> xp = XPathFactory.instance().compile("//@*", Filters.attribute());
for (Attribute a : xp.evaluate(mydoc)) {
    a.setName(a.getName().toLowerCase());
}
```

If you do not want to use XPaths (this way is also probably faster), you can loop the descendants:

```
for (Element e : mydoc.getDescendants(Filters.element())) {
    if (e.hasAttributes()) {
        for (Attribute a : e.getAttributes()) {
            a.setName(a.getName().toLowerCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Rolf